# Create a simple change password page in python

Tags: python, flask

How to create a simple change password page in python?

Should able to function in the page:

key in current-password > key in new-password and confirm-password > submit > update to database based on the username

only user who able to login had the authority to change his/her password

currently, I'm using the flask for login page

```
server = Flask(__name__)


@server.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_button_click():
    if request.form:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        
        if VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD.get(username) is None:
        # if VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD_PAIRS.get(username) is None:
   
            return """Invalid username and/or password <a href='/login'>login here</a>"""
        
        stored_pwd = VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD.get(username)['password']
        hashed_pwd = hashlib.sha256(password.encode()).hexdigest()

            
        if stored_pwd == hashed_pwd:
            login_user(User(username))
            if 'url' in session:
                if session['url']:
                    url = session['url']
                    session['url'] = None
                    return redirect(url) ## redirect to target url
            return redirect('/') ## redirect to home
        return """Invalid username and/or password <a href='/login'>login here</a>"""


pwd = pd.read_csv("pwd.csv")
VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD= pwd.set_index('username').transpose().to_dict()
```

plan to have a individually change password page

Comment: Looks like you are not using a salt when hashing passwords, this leaves you vulnerable to a rainbow table attack

Comment: Hi, could you explain in details? It is quite new to me. Apologize about this.